# Why is NeverSwitch class overriding my AlwaysSwitch class?

Tags: java, template-method-pattern

I am using the template method. I have a driver that was supplied to me that creates a Game and passes through one of two switching classes, AlwaysSwitch or NeverSwitch. The driver then creates a trial for Always Switch and a separate trial of NeverSwitch. Each trial runs 100 times and tallies how many times each case wins the game.

Both of these classes extend Game. Game has an abstract method called switching(). Both switching classes inherit this method. I put a simple print statement in both classes. `AlwaysSwitch` has "I would like to switch", while `NeverSwitch` has "I will stay."

My problem is even in the Always switch trial which creates a `new Game g = new AlwaysSwitch();`, the output is always "I will stay." and in the `new Game g = new NeverSwitch();`,  the output again is "I will stay.".

I have tried commenting out the NeverSwitch trial in the driver and only then will the AlwaysSwitch trial work.

I don't understand why the neverSwitch class is overriding the alwaysSwitch class?

```
public class Host {
    private Door prizeDoor;

    /**
     * Choose a random prize door and keep it secret.
     */
    public void choosePrizeDoor() {
        prizeDoor = Door.randomDoor();
    }

    /**
     * Reveal a door that does not contain the prize and does not
     * match the one the contestant chose.
     */
    public Door revealADoor(Door contestantChoice) {
        Door result = contestantChoice;
        // Randomly pick a door. Might iterate few times.
        while (result == contestantChoice || result == prizeDoor) {
            result = Door.randomDoor();
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the contestant's door wins or loses.
     */
    public boolean isAWinner(Door contestantChoice) {
        return prizeDoor == contestantChoice;
    }
}

/**
 * An enum representing a door. Left = 1, center = 2, right = 3.
 * Can also choose random doors here.
 * 
 * @author Todd Whittaker
 * @version 20180110
 */
public enum Door {
    LEFT(1),
    CENTER(2),
    RIGHT(3);

    private int value;
    private static final Random r = new Random();

    Door(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    /**
     * Find the door that matches the number.
     */
    public static Door valueOf(int num) {
        switch (num) {
            case 1: return LEFT;
            case 2: return CENTER;
            default: return RIGHT;
        }
    }

    /**
     * return the number matching this door.
     */
    public int valueOf() {
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Pick a random door (LEFT, CENTER, RIGHT).
     */
    public static Door randomDoor() {
        return Door.valueOf(r.nextInt(3)+1);
    }
}

public abstract class Game {

    private Host host;
    public Door contestantChoice;
    public Door revealedDoor;

    /**
     * Creates the game and its host.
     */
    public Game () {
        this.host = new Host();
    }

    /**
     * Implements the algorithm for the game:
     * 1. The host chooses which door has a prize at random.
     * 2. The contestant picks a door (left, center, or right) at random.
     * 3. The host reveals one of the two other doors that does not contain 
        the prize.
     * 4. The contestant can then switch to the other door or keep their 
        current door.
     * 5. The prize is revealed and the contestant wins or loses.
     */
    final boolean runGame() {
        host.choosePrizeDoor(); //1
        System.out.println("Let's Play");

        contestantChoice = contestantChoice.randomDoor();//2
        System.out.println("Contestant chooses " + contestantChoice);

        revealedDoor = host.revealADoor(contestantChoice); //3
        System.out.println("reveal door " + revealedDoor);

        System.out.println("would you like to switch?");
        switching();

        if(host.isAWinner(contestantChoice) == true)
        {
            System.out.println("Winner!! \n");
            return true;
        }

        System.out.println("Sorry you lose \n");

        return false;
    }

    abstract void switching();
}

public class AlwaysSwitch extends Game {
    void switching()
    {        
        System.out.println("I would like to switch" );
    }
}

public class NeverSwitch extends Game {
     void switching()
    {        
        System.out.println("I will stay." );
    }
}

public class Driver {
    private static final int TRIALS = 100;

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int switchWins = 0;
        int stayWins = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < TRIALS; ++i) {
           Game g = new AlwaysSwitch();
           if (g.runGame()) {
               ++switchWins;
           }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < TRIALS; ++i) {
            Game g = new NeverSwitch();
            if (g.runGame()) {
                ++stayWins;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Out of " + TRIALS + " trials:");
        System.out.println(" Switch won " + switchWins + " times.");
        System.out.println(" Stay won " + stayWins + " times.");
    }
}
```

All results say "I will stay."

Comment: You haven't included the source for the two switch classes.

Comment: @Jason i have edited it in.  I assumed i didn't need it because it was just print statements.

Comment: You may have copied the code into your question incorrectly. Right now, a `NeverSwitch` class cannot be cast to a `Game` because it does not extend it. In order to be able to help you, it would be good if you could provide a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem you are experiencing. At the moment, the code wouldn't compile.

Comment: @Jason it was suppose to extend Game I don’t know how that didn’t copy. But I fixed it.

Comment: Your `switching()` method never changes the door that the contestant chooses. Despite the `System.out.println` saying that the contestant switched or not, their actual choice in `contestantChoice ` never changes.

Comment: Shouldn’t the method just return the print statement.  I at this point I haven’t made code to do the actual switching. I was making sure the print statements would work.  Example since the driver makes a Game g new Game(AlwaysSwitch) shouldn’t this make the switching() method print “I would like to switch” ?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger to make sure it is calling the methods you expect it to? I can't tell if the code you've added to the question is exactly the code you are running. You mention that it always prints "I'll stay", however your code says it should print "I will stay."

Comment: I will do that tomorrow. Thank you for your suggestions

Comment: It comes from the NeverSwitch class. And called when the Game uses the switching(), is what I thought. But you might have a point here. I should try and make it switch and see what happens.

Comment: I've compiled and executed your code and it does not always output "I will stay." Given that you aren't actually switching any of the time, it does exactly what I would expect - the contestant wins approximately 1/3 of the time.

Comment: Really? I am using BlueJ and my output has not once been “I would like to change”  does the output you are getting switch between the two print statements?

Comment: The output will be 100 instances of switching, followed by 100 instances of not switching.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the code, you could change the signature of `switching()` to:

```
abstract Door switching(Door contestantsChoice, Door revealedDoor);
```

Then you would call it in `Game.runGame()` like this:

```
contestantsChoice = switching(contestantsChoice, revealedDoor);
```

Your `AlwaysSwitch` implementation would be:

```
Door switching(Door contestantChoice, Door revealedDoor)
{
    System.out.println("I would like to switch" );
    return selectRemainingDoor(contestantChoice, revealedDoor);
}

private Door selectRemainingDoor(Door contestantChoice, Door revealedDoor) {
    List<Door> doors = new ArrayList<>(asList(LEFT, CENTER, RIGHT));
    doors.remove(contestantChoice);
    doors.remove(revealedDoor);
    return doors.get(0);
}
```

And your `NeverSwitch` implementation would like like this:

```
Door switching(Door contestantChoice, Door revealedDoor)
{
    System.out.println("I will stay." );
    return contestantChoice;
}
```

Comment: Thank for your help. Greatly appreciated